# Would $\sf RP = NP$ imply $\sf NP = coNP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, probabilistic-algorithms

If $\sf RP = NP$ then the hierarchy collapses to its second level (by the Karp-Lipton theorem). But what about $\sf NP$ and $\sf coNP$?

I tried to prove that $\sf BPP$ is contained in $\sf NP$ (the other direction is trivial if $\sf RP = NP$) but to no avail, and I'm not even sure that it's true.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't think there's a particular formal reason to think so (but no reason not to either). In short, I believe it is open.

Comment: Proving $\mathbb{BPP} \subseteq \mathbb{NP}$ unconditionally is an open problem.

Answer (score 3):

If we will able prove that RP is closed under complement then we can say that
If RP = NP then it imply NP = Co-NP.

But we don't know whether RP=Co-RP or not.  BPP = P can be proved under some reasonable assumptions but RP $ \subseteq $ BPP.

If we show that RP = BPP then your statement will be correct.

*References:*

1. [RP in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_%28complexity%29)
2. [Notes on Randomized Algorithms (pdf)](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/cse200/random.pdf)
3. [RP in the Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:R#rp)

Comment: or that ​ RP = ZPP . ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

Use $\mathsf{RP=NP\implies NP\subseteq P/poly}$ in Cook and Krajicek, *Consequences of the provability of* **NP$\,\subseteq\,$P/poly** (Journal of Symbolic Logic, 72(4):1353–71, 2007; [PS](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/Pvproves.ps)).